# Code Signing Windows Drivers

Tags: windows

I am trying to code sign a driver in Windows (drivers for a video capture card). I have the inf, cat, sys files for this driver. I have followed various Windows articles and so far am able to:
1) Download a "DER" file from GoDaddy and then create a "mycompanyinc.cer" 
2) Use signtool to sign the .cat, .sys drivers 
3) verified the .cat, .sys driver files are updated with digital certifiates.They correctly stated that its issued to "my company" and issued by "go daddy CA". I exported the above certificate to a ".cer" and put on a different computer

I used MMC to make sure it shows up in the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities on the system where I need to install the drivers. While there driver file shows correctly the information "issued by" ,"issued to" etc. Windows is still complaining during drivers install that the digital signature can't be verified.

Any help, direction in this matter will be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you didn't get it cross-signed. If you do a google search you'll find that drivers require to be cross-signed, which is basically signing it with two different certificates, yours and and one of the "root"s that microsoft designates.

Comment: Thank you Joel!!! That was it! I needed to further sign the ".cat" file with the cross-cert "Root" file.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2016 Microsoft require a longer process along with an EV Code Signing Certificate for signing drivers.
They explain it in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/driver-signing) article.